# How to intergrate wordpress.com with twitter like the way it is with facebook?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, twitter

(Please note this is not a wordpress.org question)

Hi everyone,

I want every new post on my blog automatically broadcasted on twitter - the same thing is beautifully supproted with facebook. But I cannot find how to activate it on my blog at namgivu.wordpress.com.

Please help if you know how to. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@Nam Gi VU:**

In general, this is not really a WordPress question.  I'll answer it because I tend to be lenient about how related questions need to be but there's a good change another moderator will close the question and if they do I'll agree.

Basically since WordPress.com does not provide this feature you need to use a 3rd party service that will read your RSS feed and send tweets to your Twitter account:

- [**TwitterFeed**](http://twitterfeed.com/)
- [**Auto Tweet**](http://autotweet.info/)
- [**Feedburner Socialize**](http://adsenseforfeeds.blogspot.com/2009/12/socializing-your-feed-with-twitter.html) ([**Also**](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/auto-tweet-your-blog-feeds-using-feedburner-socialize-feature.html))

-Mike

P.S. One more thing. I do not recommend auto-tweeting blog posts. Most Twitter users *(myself included)* will unfollow people who auto-tweet if they recognize them doing it. I want to hear from the person, not something they've set up to run automatically. FWIW.

Comment: Please define a WordPress question & what is FWIW?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to save time doing the tedious work of creating new tweet for an already- hand-writen blog post.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU - Best way to define it is to give you examples for *"on topic"* (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500?tab=ontopic&phase=definition#tab-top and *off-topic* (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500?tab=offtopic&phase=definition#tab-top) questions. Another way to look at it is that your question could have easily have been answer over at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ because it's more about using applications as opposed to programming or theming WordPress. But it was subjective so I answered it and didn't close it.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU - One more thing, if you are serious about WordPress then seriously consider getting a self-hosted site. You can do 1000 times more with it than you can do with a site on WordPress.com.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU - Yes, it's your choice. It's not so bad if you tweet 3x more often than you post blogs, but if the only thing your Twitter feed is showing is your list of blog posts then you might as well not do it because few Twitter users are interested in other Twitter users who only use their Twitter accounts as an another *"feed"*.  This guy has a similar opinion: http://www.jeremylindh.com/why-you-shouldnt-auto-tweet-your-blog-posts/